# CRM 2011 Plugin won't update and get emails from ActivityParty

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm trying to get all emails (to, from, cc) from an email in a list and go through the list and check the contacts, if the Contact exists in CRM then a field on the email entity will be marked as true. When I check the to, from, and cc fields of the email it returns 0 parties, but there is no error there. Also at the end, when I'm calling service.Update(entity), it returns an error. `An unexpected error occurred.`

```csharp
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider
    .GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
  IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider
    .GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
  IOrganizationService service = factory
    .CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

  try
  {
  Email entity;
  if (context.MessageName == "Create")
  {
    if (context.PostEntityImages.Contains("PostImage") 
      && context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"] is Entity)
      entity = (Email)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"].ToEntity<Email>();
    else
      throw new Exception("No PostEntityImages...");
  }
  else
    throw new Exception("EmailPortalVisibilityPlugin Plugin invalid");

  if(entity.LogicalName != "email")
    throw new Exception("EmailPortalVisibilityPlugin invalid");

  bool contactExists = false;
  List<string> emails = new List<string>();
  emails.AddRange(ParseAddressUsed(entity.To, trace));
  emails.AddRange(ParseAddressUsed(entity.From, trace));
  emails.AddRange(ParseAddressUsed(entity.Cc, trace));
  foreach (String em in emails)
  {
    contactExists = LookupContact(em, service, trace);
    if (contactExists)
      break;
  }
  UpdateToggleState(entity, contactExists, service, trace);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Execute '" + ex.Message + "'");
  }
}

public List<string> ParseAddressUsed(
  IEnumerable<ActivityParty> entity, ITracingService trace)
{
  try
  {
    List<string> addressStrings = new List<string>();
    foreach (ActivityParty party in entity)
      addressStrings.Add(party.PartyId.Id.ToString());
    return addressStrings;
  }
  catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> exceptionServiceCall)
  {
    throw new Exception("ParseAddressUsed FaultException");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception("ParseAddressUsed Exception");
  }
}

public bool LookupContact(
  String emailAddress, IOrganizationService service, ITracingService trace)
{
  try
  {
    QueryByAttribute queryByAttribute = new QueryByAttribute("contact");
    queryByAttribute.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("contactId");
    queryByAttribute.Attributes.Add("emailaddress1");
    queryByAttribute.Values.Add(emailAddress);
    EntityCollection retrieved = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryByAttribute);

    return (retrieved.Entities.Count > 0);
  }
  catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> exceptionServiceCall)
  {
    throw new Exception("LookupContact Exception");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception("LookupContact Exception");
  }
}

public void UpdateToggleState(
  Email entity, bool toggleState, IOrganizationService service, ITracingService trace)
{
  try
  {
    Entity email = new Entity("email");
    email.Id = entity.Id;
    email.Attributes.Add("new_clientfacing", toggleState);
    service.Update(email);
  }
  catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> exceptionServiceCall)
  {
    throw new Exception("UpdateToggleState Exception");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception("UpdateToggleState Exception");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the first argument type of function **`ParseAddressUsed`** to `EntityCollection` instead of `IEnumerable<ActivityParty>`, and do the necessary changes.

And for the final update in function **`UpdateToggleState`**, there is no need to create a new email Entity (`Entity email = new Entity("email");`), when you already have the entity variable. You could just set the `new_clientfacing` attribute and update the entity, which is already retrieved.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to CRM 2011 plugins. I changed the first argument to `EntityCollection`, now I'm getting an error on the ParseAddressUsed function. How do I convert entity.From to EntityCollection?

Also I tried updating the entity variable in **UpdateToggleState** function using the variable i had declared originally. But that still gave me the same error.

Comment: You need to call the **ParseAddressUsed** function like this `ParseAddressUsed((EntityCollection)entity.From, trace)`

Comment: when i do that, i get an intellisense error saying: `Cannot convert 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<AcitivityParty>' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection'`

Comment: I noticed you are using both early binding and late binding in the Plugin code. You may consider using one of the two. `(EntityCollection)entity.From` could be used with the early bound type.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `ParseAddressUsed` you are adding the PartyId GUID to the string list and you use it in `LookupContact` in the emailaddress1 filter as a parameters, that is probably the reason why you are not retrieving any records.

Please try to change `addressStrings.Add(party.PartyId.Id.ToString())` to `addressStrings.Add(party.AddressUsed)` instead and see if that works.

Cheers, dimamura